# problem on downloading avi files

Tags: php

well, i have a php function here, it works fine, but when its going to send 'avi' files to a user, nothing happens. 
The point is,if user uses any browser to download 'avi' files using this script,there is no problem , but using download managers such as IDM, the script freezes up! so weird!!

Thanks

```
function downloadFile($fileLocation,$fileName,$maxSpeed = 300,$doStream=false,$type){
    if (connection_status()!=0) return(false);
    $extension = $type;
    $mime_type = "";
    /* List of File Types */
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
    $fileTypes['pdf'] = 'application/pdf';
    $fileTypes['exe'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $fileTypes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $fileTypes['doc'] = 'application/msword';
    $fileTypes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    $fileTypes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
    $fileTypes['gif'] = 'image/gif';
    $fileTypes['png'] = 'image/png';
    $fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image/jpg';
    $fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image/jpg';
    $fileTypes['rar'] = 'application/rar';    

    $fileTypes['ra'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
    $fileTypes['ram'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';
    $fileTypes['ogg'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio';

    $fileTypes['wav'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['wmv'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['avi'] = 'application/force-download';
    $fileTypes['asf'] = 'video/x-msvideo';
    $fileTypes['divx'] = 'video/x-msvideo';

    $fileTypes['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mp4'] = 'audio/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video/mpeg';
    $fileTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['m4a'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['aac'] = 'video/quicktime';
    $fileTypes['m3u'] = 'video/quicktime';

    $contentType = $fileTypes[$extension];

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."_[linkloading.ir]._".$extension."\"");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

    $contentDisposition = 'attachment';

    if($doStream == true){
        /* extensions to stream */
        $array_listen = array('mp3','m3u','m4a','mid','ogg','ra','ram','wm',
        'wav','wma','aac','3gp','avi','mov','mp4','mpeg','mpg','swf','wmv','divx','asf');
        if(in_array($extension,$array_listen)){ 
            $contentDisposition = 'inline';
        }
    }



    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");   
    $range = 0;
    $size = filesize($fileLocation);

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        list($a, $range)=explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
        str_replace($range, "-", $range);
        $size2=$size;
        $new_length=$size-$range;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range$size2/$size");
    } else {
        $size2=$size;
        header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size");
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    }

    if ($size == 0 ) { die('Zero byte file! Aborting download');}
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0); 
    $fp=fopen("$fileLocation","rb");

    fseek($fp,$range);

    while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0))
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
         print(fread($fp,127*$maxSpeed));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    return((connection_status()==0) and !connection_aborted());
}
```

Comment: I Found some errors Finally, When i changed fopen mode to "b", i've got these errors : <b>Warning</b>:  fopen(/home/linkload/public_html/down/11/02/20/Baby_Butch.avi) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Success in <b>/home/linkload/public_html/down.php</b> on line <b>104</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fseek(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in <b>/home/linkload/public_html/down.php</b> on line <b>106</b><br />
<br />

Comment: the strange thing is , when i use other modes, it does't even give me any error (i used error_reporting(E_ALL); at the script begining)!....and the file path is absolutely correct!!! 8-}

Answer (score 0):

since download managers fail to download the file, I would focus on the part where you're dealing with partial content delivery... I see nothing wierd on that download managers freezes if it gets the wrong stream data

Comment: this is an example link,which used this script: [link](http://linkloading.com/down.php?id=1788), use 111111 for username and password on idm

Comment: I'm getting Err1 and a lot of some exotic language paragraphs from that page

Comment: ahh, I see... unfortunatelly that's a bit impossible for me, since I'm not on Windows machine :-) good luck though

Answer (score 0):

I have a function for MIME Types and I see that you have a different MIME Type for AVI. Here is what I have:

```
"avi" => "video/x-msvideo"
```

The function:

```
// usage
$mime_type = getMimeType($file);

function getMimeType($file) {
    // MIME types array
    $mimeTypes = array(
        "323"       => "text/h323",
        "acx"       => "application/internet-property-stream",
        "ai"        => "application/postscript",
        "aif"       => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aifc"      => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aiff"      => "audio/x-aiff",
        "asf"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "asr"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "asx"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "au"        => "audio/basic",
        "avi"       => "video/x-msvideo",
        "axs"       => "application/olescript",
        "bas"       => "text/plain",
        "bcpio"     => "application/x-bcpio",
        "bin"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "bmp"       => "image/bmp",
        "c"         => "text/plain",
        "cat"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkiseccat",
        "cdf"       => "application/x-cdf",
        "cer"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "class"     => "application/octet-stream",
        "clp"       => "application/x-msclip",
        "cmx"       => "image/x-cmx",
        "cod"       => "image/cis-cod",
        "cpio"      => "application/x-cpio",
        "crd"       => "application/x-mscardfile",
        "crl"       => "application/pkix-crl",
        "crt"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "csh"       => "application/x-csh",
        "css"       => "text/css",
        "dcr"       => "application/x-director",
        "der"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "dir"       => "application/x-director",
        "dll"       => "application/x-msdownload",
        "dms"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "doc"       => "application/msword",
        "dot"       => "application/msword",
        "dvi"       => "application/x-dvi",
        "dxr"       => "application/x-director",
        "eps"       => "application/postscript",
        "etx"       => "text/x-setext",
        "evy"       => "application/envoy",
        "exe"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "fif"       => "application/fractals",
        "flr"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "gif"       => "image/gif",
        "gtar"      => "application/x-gtar",
        "gz"        => "application/x-gzip",
        "h"         => "text/plain",
        "hdf"       => "application/x-hdf",
        "hlp"       => "application/winhlp",
        "hqx"       => "application/mac-binhex40",
        "hta"       => "application/hta",
        "htc"       => "text/x-component",
        "htm"       => "text/html",
        "html"      => "text/html",
        "htt"       => "text/webviewhtml",
        "ico"       => "image/x-icon",
        "ief"       => "image/ief",
        "iii"       => "application/x-iphone",
        "ins"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
        "isp"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
        "jfif"      => "image/pipeg",
        "jpe"       => "image/jpeg",
        "jpeg"      => "image/jpeg",
        "jpg"       => "image/jpeg",
        "js"        => "application/x-javascript",
        "latex"     => "application/x-latex",
        "lha"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "lsf"       => "video/x-la-asf",
        "lsx"       => "video/x-la-asf",
        "lzh"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "m13"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "m14"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "m3u"       => "audio/x-mpegurl",
        "man"       => "application/x-troff-man",
        "mdb"       => "application/x-msaccess",
        "me"        => "application/x-troff-me",
        "mht"       => "message/rfc822",
        "mhtml"     => "message/rfc822",
        "mid"       => "audio/mid",
        "mny"       => "application/x-msmoney",
        "mov"       => "video/quicktime",
        "movie"     => "video/x-sgi-movie",
        "mp2"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mp3"       => "audio/mpeg",
        "mpa"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpe"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpeg"      => "video/mpeg",
        "mpg"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpp"       => "application/vnd.ms-project",
        "mpv2"      => "video/mpeg",
        "ms"        => "application/x-troff-ms",
        "mvb"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "nws"       => "message/rfc822",
        "oda"       => "application/oda",
        "p10"       => "application/pkcs10",
        "p12"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
        "p7b"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
        "p7c"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
        "p7m"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
        "p7r"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
        "p7s"       => "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
        "pbm"       => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
        "pdf"       => "application/pdf",
        "pfx"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
        "pgm"       => "image/x-portable-graymap",
        "pko"       => "application/ynd.ms-pkipko",
        "pma"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmc"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pml"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmr"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmw"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pnm"       => "image/x-portable-anymap",
        "pot"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "ppm"       => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
        "pps"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "ppt"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "prf"       => "application/pics-rules",
        "ps"        => "application/postscript",
        "pub"       => "application/x-mspublisher",
        "qt"        => "video/quicktime",
        "ra"        => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "ram"       => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "ras"       => "image/x-cmu-raster",
        "rgb"       => "image/x-rgb",
        "rmi"       => "audio/mid",
        "roff"      => "application/x-troff",
        "rtf"       => "application/rtf",
        "rtx"       => "text/richtext",
        "scd"       => "application/x-msschedule",
        "sct"       => "text/scriptlet",
        "setpay"    => "application/set-payment-initiation",
        "setreg"    => "application/set-registration-initiation",
        "sh"        => "application/x-sh",
        "shar"      => "application/x-shar",
        "sit"       => "application/x-stuffit",
        "snd"       => "audio/basic",
        "spc"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
        "spl"       => "application/futuresplash",
        "src"       => "application/x-wais-source",
        "sst"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkicertstore",
        "stl"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkistl",
        "stm"       => "text/html",
        "svg"       => "image/svg+xml",
        "sv4cpio"   => "application/x-sv4cpio",
        "sv4crc"    => "application/x-sv4crc",
        "t"         => "application/x-troff",
        "tar"       => "application/x-tar",
        "tcl"       => "application/x-tcl",
        "tex"       => "application/x-tex",
        "texi"      => "application/x-texinfo",
        "texinfo"   => "application/x-texinfo",
        "tgz"       => "application/x-compressed",
        "tif"       => "image/tiff",
        "tiff"      => "image/tiff",
        "tr"        => "application/x-troff",
        "trm"       => "application/x-msterminal",
        "tsv"       => "text/tab-separated-values",
        "txt"       => "text/plain",
        "uls"       => "text/iuls",
        "ustar"     => "application/x-ustar",
        "vcf"       => "text/x-vcard",
        "vrml"      => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "wav"       => "audio/x-wav",
        "wcm"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wdb"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wks"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wmf"       => "application/x-msmetafile",
        "wps"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wri"       => "application/x-mswrite",
        "wrl"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "wrz"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xaf"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xbm"       => "image/x-xbitmap",
        "xla"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlc"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlm"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xls"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlsx"      => "vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlt"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlw"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xof"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xpm"       => "image/x-xpixmap",
        "xwd"       => "image/x-xwindowdump",
        "z"         => "application/x-compress",
        "zip"       => "application/zip"
    );

    $extension = end(explode('.', $file));
    return $mimeTypes[$extension]; // return the array value
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the function. I've tried this but nothing changed :( , IDM still freezes on "connecting..." Status when it's avi.